# how can create pages inside a codeIgniter controller method

Tags: codeigniter

I am building  a site using codeIgniter. My problem is I cant control my controller if my URI contains more then two segments. see http://example.com/products/woven/men. I want to make category of men look like http://example.com/products/woven/men/shirts or anything. my **products** controller and **men** method is dynamic but I cant create any segment of men. my controller is

```
class Products extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product_model');
 }

public function index(){
        $data['title']='Products';
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('products/navigator');
        $this->load->view('products/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function woven($page='home'){
    $data['woven_men']=$this->product_model->woven_men();
    $data['woven_women']=$this->product_model->woven_women();
    $data['woven_children']=$this->product_model->woven_children();
    $data['title']=  "Woven : ".ucfirst($page);


    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('products/navigator');
    $this->load->view('products/woven/'.$page);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
}
```

I know It possible to create more segment using method parameter. but how can use this inside woven method like shirt, pant, shorts etc

Comment: When you go to `http://example.com/products/woven/men/shirts`, CodeIgniter opens your `products` controller and calls your `woven` method with 2 parameters: `'men'` and `'shirts'` (just like if you were to do `woven('men', 'shirts');`).

Comment: but how can i only use  $this->load->view('products/woven/men/'.$men_category); //$men_category is the second parameter of woven

Comment: I'm confused here.  What's the problem?  What if you made a `woven_men` and a `woven_women` method in your controller?  Would that help?  I'm not really understanding the issue here.

Comment: woven_men is the woven products of men and woven_women is the woven products of women

Comment: Yeah, instead of having one method, have two.  I'm still not sure of the issue here, so I was just throwing out ideas.

Comment: I use just different query

Comment: please see a model method.         public function woven_men(){
                $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product 
                                         WHERE product_dept_id=1 
                                         AND
                                         product_type_id=1
                                         ORDER BY `product`.`product_id` DESC 
                                         LIMIT 0 , 6
 
                                         ");
                return $query->result_array();
        }

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking or what you are having trouble with.  Is the solution just `if($page === 'men'){$data['woven_men']=$this->product_model->woven_men();} elseif($page ==='women'){$data['woven_women']=$this->product_model->woven_women();}`?

Comment: I have not trouble in woven_men or woven_women. let I have a table which will be classified of woven_men or woven_women. if uri is http://example.com/products/woven/men/shirts I want shirts.php in my view inside view/products/woven/men/ folder.

Comment: Ok, so what's the issue?  You can have as many sub-folders as you want in your views.  `/application/views/products/woven/men/shirts.php` can be loaded by doing `$this->load->view('products/woven/men/shirts');`

Comment: how can I load $this->load->view('products/woven/men/'.$men_category);

Comment: `public function woven($page='home', $type=''){` then `$this->load->view('products/woven/'.$page.'/'.$type);`.  So when you go to `http://example.com/products/woven/men/shirts` it'll load that view.

Comment: It Works.. and also sorry for my weak expression

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30504/discussion-between-emon-and-rocket-hazmat)